# What is wrong with this mmap system call?

Tags: go

This is an attempt to `mmap` a file and write a single byte:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.Open("/tmp/data")
    mmap, _ := syscall.Mmap(int(file.Fd()), 0, 100, syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
    fmt.Printf("cap is %d", cap(mmap))
    mmap[0] = 0
    syscall.Munmap(mmap)
}
```

Despite length is set to 100, `mmap` capacity is always 0. What went wrong in the system call?

Comment: You ignore errors. Don't do that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always check for error!

`os.Open` opens a file for reading only, however `mmap` call asks to map the file read/write, thus giving a permission denied error, and as a result mapped region size is 0.

Answer (score -1):

Is the file `/tmp/data` empty? If so:

I think you cannot pass arbitrary `length` parameter (like 100 in your case) to [`Mmap`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mmap). I think this parameter must be <= `file.Size()`, ie the the size of the file referred to by fd. If that's the case then try to make your data file non-empty and try again.